# Error in saving the query(Join expression not supported. (Error 3296))

Tags: sql, ms-access

Here is my base code and the note point is i already retreived dbo_currencyconversion table from two more tables of tbl_variable costs and tbl_currencies.
Now iam trying to add row values from the table dbo_currencyconversion and the query is working fine in adding rows but iam getting an error while iam trying to save the query in MS ACCESS please let me know if there is any meathod to solve this problem 
Here is my query in ms access

```
select 
currencyconversion_1ST_P_OLD.MEA_ID,
currencyconversion_1ST_P_OLD.conversion-currencyconversion_OFR_P_NEW.conversion as delta
from 
dbo_currencyconversion as currencyconversion_1ST_P_OLD INNER JOIN
dbo_currencyconversion as currencyconversion_OFR_P_NEW ON 

(currencyconversion_1ST_P_OLD.VCOS_NAME='1ST_P_OLD' AND 

currencyconversion_OFR_P_NEW.VCOS_NAME='OFR_P_NEW' AND 

currencyconversion_1ST_P_OLD.MEA_ID=currencyconversion_OFR_P_NEW.MEA_ID);
```

Error is: 
Join expression not supported. **(Error 3296)**

Possible causes:

Your SQL statement contains multiple joins in which the results of the query can differ, depending on the order in which the joins are performed. You may want to create a separate query to perform the first join, and then include that query in your SQL statement. 
The ON statement in your JOIN operation is incomplete or contains too many tables. You may want to put your ON expression in a WHERE clause.

Thank you for your response in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
currencyconversion_1ST_P_OLD.MEA_ID,
currencyconversion_1ST_P_OLD.conversion-currencyconversion_OFR_P_NEW.conversion as delta
FROM
dbo_currencyconversion as currencyconversion_1ST_P_OLD 
INNER JOIN dbo_currencyconversion as currencyconversion_OFR_P_NEW 
ON currencyconversion_1ST_P_OLD.MEA_ID=currencyconversion_OFR_P_NEW.MEA_ID
WHERE
(((currencyconversion_1ST_P_OLD.VCOS_NAME)="1ST_P_OLD") AND 
((currencyconversion_OFR_P_NEW.VCOS_NAME)="OFR_P_NEW"));
```

Comment: are all these "(" and ")" actually needed in this where condition?

Comment: @rakeshjain Who knows, Access tend to create queries with a lot of parenthesis. This is what a query made inside Access using the query tool would look like. I suspect that they might not be needed though.

Comment: I have a general question regarding MS ACCESS like if i want to add this query to my form is there any procedure to do it.As i need this query to input in my Ratio Data base so if there is any process of inputing this query to a MS access form please tell me

Comment: I have typically 20 forms which are based on queries and each query has its own logic to implement in forms so i need to implement multiple queries in single form some times so please guide me regarding how to add my queries to form of 'MS ACCESS'

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to move

```
currencyconversion_1ST_P_OLD.VCOS_NAME='1ST_P_OLD' AND 
currencyconversion_OFR_P_NEW.VCOS_NAME='OFR_P_NEW'
```

part from your ON condition to inside where clause.

Final Query

```
select 
currencyconversion_1ST_P_OLD.MEA_ID,
currencyconversion_1ST_P_OLD.conversion-currencyconversion_OFR_P_NEW.conversion as delta
from 
dbo_currencyconversion as currencyconversion_1ST_P_OLD INNER JOIN
dbo_currencyconversion as currencyconversion_OFR_P_NEW 
ON (currencyconversion_1ST_P_OLD.MEA_ID=currencyconversion_OFR_P_NEW.MEA_ID)
WHERE currencyconversion_1ST_P_OLD.VCOS_NAME='1ST_P_OLD' AND 
currencyconversion_OFR_P_NEW.VCOS_NAME='OFR_P_NEW';
```

Comment: Can you please make it on my above code i dont know how to move it to where clause i tried it but it is always giving some syntax errors.

Comment: I have a general question regarding MS ACCESS like if i want to add this query to my form is there any procedure to do it.As i need this query to input in my Ratio Data base so if there is any process of inputing this query to a MS access form please tell me